# How to optimize 2D game unity (EarlyUpdate.PlayerCleanupCacheData)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization

I had a problem with the optimization of the game on unity. How not trying anyway, there are still little friezes. I deleted unnecessary objects, optimized the code to the minimum according to the rules, reduced the resolution of the images, and it seems that everything has been fixed, but a small nuance - Almost every second there are small friezes, despite the fact that the processor is not loaded at all (40-50%), the memory is 100 mb (it was -400), fps 60 always, there is practically nothing objects on the scene, but there are lags. One of these issues is PlayerCleanupCachedData. How to get rid of it so that for every 10 seconds it happens?[image]

Comment: Of you look at the values `PlayerCleanupCachedData` seems not to be that big deal actually ... Anyway did you try to unfold the items and see into them to see what takes long there? Note however that even the debugger itself might slow down the execution also building and running as `Debug` is slower than building and running as `Release`

Comment: I have encountered this issue when I enabled Graphics Jobs in the player settings. Disabling it completely removed this overhead (ofcourse you might have different performance impacts now.)